# Ad in featured snippet of Stack Overflow Google search result

Tags: discussion, support

I just googled for `ng-dirty` and got the following result:

[image: Google result for ng-dirty]

I use all possible adblock options, so I was surprised to see an ad there. However, it seems that this is just an image that Google crawled from Stack Ooverflow, and clicking it just opens the image.

Could it be that Stack Overflow tricks Google into displaying the ad?

Or is this just a random nonsensical thing that Google does because it couldn't find a meaningful picture for this snippet?